# What is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> What is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q$ with $q$ being some power of a prime $p$ ?

I wrote, ''the algebraic closure'' because, they're the same up to isomorphism right ?

It cannot be finite, otherwise it is not algebraically closed, so how does it look like ?

Comment: What sort of answer would help you? I don't think there is any "nice" description of this, other than the fact that it will be the same for any power of $p$.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://planetmath.org/algebraicclosureofafinitefield) has the information you're looking for

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm studying finite fields http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/09.pdf#page=2 (Proof on the top of page 2) it is written that Frobenius stabilizes all fields between $F_1$ and $E$, but $E$ should be infinite, i find this a bit strange

Comment: What is strange about $E$ being infinite?

Answer (score 12):

Given finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ with $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ then the compositum is the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^{mn}}$. This allows us to define the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ as the
union
$$
\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}=\bigcup_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^k}.
$$
For prime powers $q=p^n$ the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$ can be constructed by building and gluing $\ell$-adic towers
$$
\mathbb{F}_{q}\subset \mathbb{F}_{q^{\ell}}\subset \mathbb{F}_{q^{\ell^2}}\subset \cdots
$$
see [here](http://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4836&context=etd) for an algorithm and an impressive picture on page $5$.

Comment: If you have $$\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}=\bigcup_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$$, why do you still bother about $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$? It is just $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$, since $$\mathbb{F}_{q}/\mathbb{F}_{p}$$ is algebraic...

Comment: Because these $\ell$-adic towers are interesting in itself, e.g., for computing roots in $\mathbb{F}_q$ quickly.

Comment: Instead of using a single prime $\ell$ at a time, an alternative is to use the tower of extensions $\Bbb{F}_{q^{m!}}\subset\Bbb{F}_{q^{(m+1)!}}$. The factorials cover all the prime powers and their gcds in due time. +1 of course