# Fixpoints of the frobenius homomorphism in the algebraic closure of a finite field

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-curves

I have a questiion about a statement about Galoistheory in Silvermans book on elliptic curves. In particular i want to know why
[image]

this statement holds. of course, one direction is clear, but i cant seem to understand why P is already in $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ just because $\Phi(P)=P$. An elementary explanation would be nice too, because my course in Galois theory was too long ago for me to actually remember how everything fitted together. Thanks!

Comment: If $P=(x,y)$ then $\Phi(P)=(x^q,y^q)$. This is equal to $P$ if and only if $x^q=x$ and $y^q=y$ if and only if $P\in  E(\Bbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: Yeah, but why? i dont see iwhy thats the case if (x,y) are potentially elements of the algebraic closure.

Comment: @Adronic Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873807/what-is-the-algebraic-closure-of-mathbb-f-q help? If not, I'd suggest thinking about the Galois theory of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}/\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ for various $n$ carefully.

Comment: An element $x\in\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$ satisfies the equation $x^q=x$ if and only if  $x\in\Bbb{F}_q$. Either by Galois theory or by the properties of $\Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: I am asking for precisely that argument